# Ionic demo app does not appear in emulator

Tags: android, ionic2

I am building the "cutePuppyPics" demo app in Ionic 2.  It works in a Web browser and in an iOS simulator.  But when I build for Android, the app doesn't appear and there are no error messages.  Here is what I see in the Terminal window:

```
$ ionic run android
• You're trying to build for android, but don't have the platform installed yet.
∆ Installing android for you.
√ Installed platform android

∆ Compiling Sass to CSS
√ Matching patterns: app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss

∆ Copying fonts
√ Matching patterns: node_modules/ionic-framework/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)

∆ Copying HTML
√ Matching patterns: app/**/*.html

∆ Compiling and bundling with Webpack...
√ Using your webpack.config.js file
√ Sass compilation complete
√ HTML copied to www/build
√ Compiling files complete.

Hash: 855722ed018197485183
Version: webpack 1.12.10
Time: 7550ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  2.67 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
    + 361 hidden modules

√ Webpack complete

√ Fonts copied to www/build/fonts
Running command: /Users/susancrayne/cutePuppyPics/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/susancrayne/cutePuppyPics
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/susancrayne/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
No target specified, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_23_for_BernieAppAndroid
Waiting for emulator...
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable was incorrect.